# How to dismiss multiple choice dialog from within onDestroy

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

My code currently creates dialogs which may need to be dismissed when the device is rotated. As such, for certain dialogs i have a global declaration and then code as follows:

```
Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialog = dialog.create();
        alertDialog.setMessage("Some Heading");
        alertDialog.setButton(alertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Some Message", dialogClickListener);
        alertDialog.setButton(alertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Another Message", dialogClickListener);

        alertDialog.show();
```

In onDestroy, I can then check if the dialog is visible and destroy it if that is the case:

```
if ((alertDialog !=null) && (alertDialog.isShowing()))
{
    alertDialog.dismiss();
}
```

The above works fine for basic Text and button based dialogs, however I also have dialogs that deal with multiple choice selections such as checkboxes and radio buttons.

Those are current setup as such:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogMultipleChoice = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

dialogMultipleChoice.setMultiChoiceItems(myList, myCheckedList, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which, boolean isChecked) {
    checkedList[which] = isChecked;
     }}
);
```

... and so on..

With the multiple choice dialog, I cannot see how I can dismiss this in onDestroy, i.e. I have no ability to call dialogMultipleChoice.dismiss().

Note, I cannot use dialog.create as, if I do, I will not be able to call setMultiChoiceItems.

Any help in resolving this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you are creating the builder and then assign the value of `builder.create();` to your member variable:

```
Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alertDialog = dialog.create();
```

But in the second example you are just creating a local variable:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogMultipleChoice = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

You need to call `alertDialog = dialog.create();` to assign this dialog to the member variable and then you can dismiss it like the other dialog

Comment: Hi Katharina, unfortunately that won't work. The reason I didn't do that is because if I use dialog.create, I can't then assign multichoiceitems. That isn't support in that method so this won't work.

Comment: call `dialog.create()`after assigning the items to the builder

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used assigned the return value of the .show() call to dialog, i.e. dialog = dialogMultipleChoice.show();